# Center (wide) SVG Element within (smaller) Container while keeping original SVG width

Tags: html, css, svg

## Issue:

Not able to center a wide svg (while retaining its original width and height) within a 'not-as-wide' container.

## Steps:

I've design an SVG element that has a default width of `3000px` which I want to preserve (I don't want it to scale or use `width=100%` to shrink or extend the SVG).

I want to place the SVG element within a container that has a `width="100%"` and a fixed height, let's say `250px`. I'm trying to center the SVG, such as if my screen was only `1280px` wide, the first portion (and last) `860px` of the svg would not be visible.

*Calculation: (3000-1280)/2 = 860 *

Any idea or help on how to achieve this? I've tried using transform/translate to move the SVG inside the container but no positive results...

I'm getting hopeless :(

## Code:

(edited to include original styled-components implementation)

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

// Using styled-components 
const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;

    svg {
        opacity:1;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

`;

class App extends React.Component {
render(){
return <Container>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="3000" height="250" viewBox="0 0 3000 250">
        <path
            id="Path_19510"
            data-name="Path 19510"
            d="M3000,477s-200,5-356,115-336,106-423,65c-42.736-20.14-85.29-30.391-117.537-35.613-39.32-8.192-83.3-7.111-121.162,1.629-100.53,23.2-271.333,200.166-392.685,78.826-108.44-108.422-192.276-65.146-231.863-79.47-51.647-18.685-39.84-75.2-109.955-102.123-44.932-17.247-111.989,2.153-169.479,21.616l-.028.01h0c-31.022,10.5-59.25,21.016-79.711,25.8a266.054,266.054,0,0,1-47.2,4q-6.693-.333-13.233-1.2C886.09,560.723,855.088,493.629,802,474c-119-44-240,40-425,128C199.67,686.351,0,463,0,463V768l1168.438-.005L2140,768h860Z"
            transform="translate(0 -461.932)"
fill="#000"
        />
    </svg>
</Container>
}
}
```

## Visual desired result:

[Desired result to be achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQzmd.jpg)

Comment: You have an error in your CSS.  Your `svg` element isn't being styled at all.  Try it by setting for example `opacity: 0.2;` within the `svg` block.  You should move the `svg` in your css outside of the `.container` rule.

Comment: Unless you're **really** using SCSS or some similar preprocessor, rather than plain CSS.

Comment: @user2740650 I'm using styled-component, so technically, it looks more like this : 

`const Container = styled.div`[styles from above]`

Comment: OK, well you posted invalid CSS and labelled it as CSS :-) .  Please correct your post so that others don't waste time debugging a problem that you're not really experiencing.  You should provide a simple example without errors, or be clear about your context.  Ideally you could produce a self-contained example that people can try out (eg. on codepen or some such).

Comment: @user2740650 Just updated to include styled-components. I initially removed it, as this is not an issue related to styled-components or react, but instead css and svg... Hope this help clarify my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do is add the following to the SVG.

```
<svg ... preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
   ...etc...
</svg>
```